# finding xpath to the value

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0

I want to get the value{namevalue1} from the xPath for the below xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<properties>
    <entry key="name1">namevalue1</entry>
    <entry key="name2">namevalue2</entry>
</properties>
```

What is the xPath for the value1?

Comment: `/properties/entry[@key='name1']`...

Comment: @JeffMercado :  I just want the value i.e. 'namevalue1' . But, above solution gives me whole entry '<entry key="name1">namevalue1</entry>'

Comment: Are you doing this in a particular programming language?  This would help us give you a more focused answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what Jeff proposed, you'll need to append a `text()` to get just the text node:

```
% < in.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<properties>
    <entry key="name1">namevalue1</entry>
    <entry key="name2">namevalue2</entry>
</properties>
% xpquery '/properties/entry[@key="name1"]/text()' in.xml
namevalue1
%
```

Comment: I am not supposed to use any function e.g. text()

Comment: `text()` is not a function, it is a node-type test.  The only purpose of the empty parens is to indicate to XPath that you are not looking for a node called `<text>`,

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
/properties/entry[@key='name1']/text()
```

Comment: I am not supposed to use any function like text(). Is there any way to do it without function?

Comment: Not that I know of ... why can you not use functions? They are a part of the Xpath specification.

Comment: The text() function is listed in section 2.5 of the Xpath spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev ... why can it not be used?